# Bash script validating the last 4 characters of an input

Tags: linux, bash

I was wondering if it is possible to check the last 4 characters of an input and if it doesnt match a certain string or if the input is empty then tell the user the error and return them to the prompt?

What i have so far just checks for blank input and if theres nothing there it dumps the user back to a prompt, but i cant figure out how to do what i need it to do.

```
read -p "Please enter username ( i.e clientname-ssl ): " userInput
if [[ -z "$userInput" ]]; then
    printf '%s\n' "No input entered"
    exit 1
else
    printf "You entered %s " "$userInput"
    printf '\n'
    ls -l /home/"$userInput"
fi
```

I need to make sure the user always enters the username followed by '-ssl'

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a *recursive function* :

```
do_ask() {
    read -p "Please enter username ( i.e clientname-ssl ): " userInput
    if [[ -z "$userInput" ]]; then
        printf '%s\n' "No input entered"
        exit 1
    else
        printf "You entered %s " "$userInput"
        if [[ $userInput == *-ssl ]]; then
            printf '\n'
            ls -l "/home/$userInput"
        else
            echo "ERROR: missing *-ssl"
            do_ask
        fi
    fi
}

do_ask
```